# Dragging UITextView Around Screen

Tags: swift, uitextview

I'm trying to allow the user to draw a UITextView around the screen like in the SnapChat app. I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? I don't thin the detectPan method is being called. Do I have to override some UITextFieldDelegate property?

```
var panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"detectPan:")
text.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

func detectPan(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
        var translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
        sender.view!.center = CGPointMake(sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

Comment: if you add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()' after translation is made, does it solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about this but I put the textview in a view and disabled user interactions. Then made a tap gesture (which makes the textview the first responder) and pan gesture (which moves the view).